# SQL Sub Queries and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL in PHPMyAdmin and want to figure out if my solutions are okay or if I am doing something that isn't the best standard. Thank you.

> author (ID, FirstName, LastName, YearOfBirth, Gender, LivingCityID)
>
> book (ID, Name, Type, YearPublished, PublisherID, SoldBookCount)
>
> writes (BookID, AuthorID)
>
> city (ID, CityName, Country)
>
> publisher (ID, PublisherName, PublisherCityID)

Finding the ID of all books that are not published in the residence cities of its authors. One book may have several authors.

```
SELECT w.BookID
FROM author as a, book as b, writes as w, publisher as p
WHERE a.LivingCityID != p.PublisherCityId AND w.AuthorID = a.ID AND w.BookID = b.ID AND p.ID = b.PublisherID
ORDER BY w.BookID ASC
```

The next two are basically the same but I think what I wrote is sloppy. What is a better way to do this?

Find the ID of the publisher who published books before year 1600 **OR** after year 1900, but did not publish any book between year 1600 and year 1900.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PublisherID
FROM book
WHERE PublisherID NOT IN (SELECT PublisherID
 FROM book
 WHERE YearPublished >=1600 AND YearPublished <= 1900)
```

Find the ID of the publisher who published books before year 1600 **AND** after year 1900, but did not publish any book between year 1600 and year 1900.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PublisherID
FROM book
WHERE PublisherID NOT IN (SELECT PublisherID
 FROM book
 WHERE YearPublished >=1600 AND YearPublished <= 1900)
      AND PublisherID IN (SELECT PublisherID
FROM book
WHERE YearPublished < 1600)
      AND PublisherID IN (SELECT PublisherID
FROM book
WHERE YearPublished > 1900)
```

Comment: Use explicit `JOIN` for start instead of old syntax of joining tables in `WHERE`. :)

Comment: The INNER JOIN is much more readable. SELECT ... FROM author INNER JOIN book ON author.AuthorID=book.AuthorID

Comment: OP, some of your past questions seem to have been reasonably answered. I'd urge you to consider marking one of the answers to this and past questions as answered, if the answer(s) have helped you.

Comment: Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`, since the `NOT IN` result when NULL's are returned is not what many people expect.

Comment: 1. Please format your text to reflect its parse. 2. Your use of IN plus subselects suggests you might benefit from learning how JOIN is simpler in those cases. PS It turns out safer in terms of typos to use AS in SELECT and not use it in FROM.

Answer (score 3):

I think you did quite well. Nothing below is drastically different from what you did; information below just adds a different perspective.

**First**

The first query can be written using `JOIN`s like so:

```
SELECT w.BookID
FROM book b
LEFT JOIN writes w on w.bookid = book.id
LEFT JOIN author a on a.id = w.authorid
LEFT JOIN publisher p on p.id = b.publisherid
WHERE NOT a.LivingCityID = p.PublisherCityId
ORDER BY w.BookID ASC
```

Use `where` clause for filtering information. Use `join` clauses for showing relationship. If you want all books, I'd put it as the first table in the SQL for ease of reading (personal opinion, and it counts when doing left joins).

**Second**

The second query could be rewritten as

```
SELECT DISTINCT publisherid
FROM book b
INNER JOIN publisher p on p.id = b.publisherid
WHERE    NOT    b.yearpublished BETWEEN 1600 and 1900
```

In this scenario, we are asking for books `not` published in year between 1600 and 1900 (including 1600 and 1900 years). We also join books and publisher to get publisher information.

Alternate way of writing this query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT publisherid
FROM publisher p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM book 
    WHERE    NOT    yearpublished BETWEEN 1600 and 1900
        AND publisherid = p.id
)
```

Here we are asking publisher table to check if there's any record in books matching our particular need. If it is, great...do a select. Otherwise, move on on to the next record.

Nice read: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx. Even though the blog is about SQL Server, the philosophy applies.

**Third**

Your query appears just fine. Added is an example below using the `exists` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT publisherid
FROM publisher p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM book 
    WHERE    NOT    yearpublished BETWEEN 1600 and 1900
        AND publisherid = p.id
) 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM book 
    WHERE yearpublished < 1600
        AND publisherid = p.id
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM book 
    WHERE yearpublished > 1900
        AND publisherid = p.id
)
```

The deal with `in` clause is that if there are thousands of publisherid meeting criteria of `>1900`, your query could become slow (depends on optimizer too). `exists` clause could help overcome some of the limitations of `in`.

Alternate way of writing this is:

```
SELECT publisherid
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CASE WHEN yearpublished < 1600 THEN 1600 ELSE 1900 END AS yr,
        publisherid
    FROM book b
    INNER JOIN publisher p on p.id = b.publisherid
    WHERE    NOT    b.yearpublished BETWEEN 1600 and 1900
) t
GROUP BY yr
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Here we create a subquery and give it an alias of `t`. This subquery combines books and publishers and ignores the records where yearpublished was undesired. Selection is done of the publisherid and a `case` statement is used as a marker. Years <1600 are marked with 1600. Years >1900 are marked with 1900. That gives us results like so:

```
1600  publisherid#1
1600  publisherid#1
1900  publisherid#1
1600  publisherid#2
1600  publisherid#3
1900  publisherid#3
...
```

Using distinct, we shorten the result to something like this:

```
1600  publisherid#1    |
1900  publisherid#1    | --> this and above record will become a group
1600  publisherid#2
1600  publisherid#3    |
1900  publisherid#3    | --> this and above record will become a group
...
```

Now we group by publisher id and ask for only those publisher ids that have a count of 2. #1 and #3 will meet our criteria in the above example.

**Note**

These queries are not tested. They just showcase different ways of writing queries and highlight certain differences. Which one is fast, which one is slow? - that depends on your data, indexing and results from `explain` and runtimes.

My general patterns

- use `joins` over `where` to combine tables
- use `exists` over `in`
- check results of `explain` and actual runtime with dummy dataset
- add index to cover grouping and filtering and ordering
- add index hints to see if queries perform faster using an index we have hinted on using